# Install php-devel on osx

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, installation

I can't install mongo because pecl fail with this error :

```
ERROR : phpize failed
```

I read on internet that phpize fail when php-devel is not correctly installed.
So I try to install php-devel. But the only way available on osx seem to be macports.
So I install macports and launch :

```
sudo port install php5-devel

Error: php5-devel has been made obsolete by the port php5. Please install php5 instead.
Error: org.macports.configure for port php5-devel returned: obsolete port
```

I have the php 5.4.14 version but I found that macport install php-devel for version 5.3 so there is the previous error.

But how can I install mongo and so php-devel on osx ? On linux, I see that yum integrate this functionality. But on osx I found anything ! :'(

And what is the function of php-devel tool ?
I see it exists php5-devel tool. I must install php-devel, php5-devel or the both ?!

Thank you ! :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative way to install mongo and the last php version. [Auto-install PHP 5.4](http://php-osx.liip.ch/). Maybe it isn't the best way but it works good for me.

Good bye !